# Get phone contacts without the photos in order to save them in a DataOutputStream(vcf format)

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have an application that export the phone contacts to the sdcard in a vcf format.

**I am able** to get all the vcards and save them in a vcf format(looping on every ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY until the cursor count -1 is reached in order to put the vcard concerning each contact in a AssetFileDescriptor and then converted to an FileInputStream using getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(....) ). The problem is that now I need to save the vcards **without** the photo.

So any idea how to get the contacts **without their photo** in order to save them on the external storage in a vcf format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Clone the non-photo data from existing vcards into blank vcards before storage?

Comment: @CeilingGecko didn't get your idea

Comment: @AndroidNabs I think he meant you should create a new vcard for every vcard and copy all the data but the picture and save the new vcard

Comment: @OriWasserman I got it, but don't you think it's a hard and heavy method on the device ? I am looking for a method to query all the rows of the contacts without the photo row. Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**API Level 14 +**

If you check out the source for [ContactsContract.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/provider/ContactsContract.java/), you can see that they introduced a new way to exclude the contact photo.

```
/**
 * Boolean parameter that may be used with {@link #CONTENT_VCARD_URI}
 * and {@link #CONTENT_MULTI_VCARD_URI} to indicate that the returned
 * vcard should not contain a photo.
 *
 * @hide
 */
 public static final String QUERY_PARAMETER_VCARD_NO_PHOTO = "nophoto";
```

The constant is hidden from the API (@hide), but you can still take advantage of it.

After you get your lookup key, you can get the "nophoto" vcard Uri using the following code:

```
String lookupKey = cursor.getString(
                 cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
Uri vcardUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI
             .buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("nophoto", String.valueOf(true))
             .build();
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(vcardUri, lookupKey);
```

**Pre API level 14**

Your only solution would be to build your own vcards using the contact information.

This [library](https://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/) might help.

Comment: your method work like a charm, I will use the "nophoto" parameter for API>14, and I will handle the API<14 by processing the vcards using external libraries. Thanks for your help